# Converting older spinner style to newer style

Tags: android

I know this may sound a trivial question, but I can't figure it out on my own. I've Googled and searched many many times. I know it may have a simple solution but I don't know where to search anymore. In general, I'm a Windows programmer, but I started programming for Android about 4 months ago. I've developed a fairly extensive application. The problem began when I started programming...my spinners are the solid gray rectangular style (unlike the newer style with the triangle in the lower right corner). When I started developing this app several months ago, I couldn't figure out why my spinners were different (after many hours) so I just ignored it. I'm at the point now of polishing my program and want the newer spinner style. So, I'm beating my head against the wall again. I went to my Android SDK Manager in Eclipse and updated my Android SDK Tools, Platform-tools, and Build-tools. I have the latest versions of all of these (22.3 and 19.0.1). When I create a new project, the newer spinner style appears. However, none of my older projects changed. They still have the same old gray, rectangular type spinners. I tried using a "android format" line command I found while Googling, but no luck with that either. I know there is probably something really simple I can do, but I can't find it. Can anyone help me with this? I'm using ADT Bundle with build v22.2.1-833290 on a Mac OSX Mavericks.

Comment: Put some code or error and also you can explain in short form. no one has time to read

Answer (score 0):

Newer spinner style works from API level 11.

So, you have to run in Android 3.0 and higher devices. If u want the same style in below 3.0 versions, then you have to customize your style. Like, take that newer style type of image and apply as a background to the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ActionBarSherlock in your code. This will give you an advantage to have actionbar in lower versions of android. Also it contains ICSSpinner(An alternative to androids default spinner), which will give the newer look of spinners in lower versions of android.

Here's the link for ActionBarSherlock

http://actionbarsherlock.com/